# Extracting tar files from an S3 bucket to another S3 bucket using Python

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, zip, boto3, tar

We need to extract the contents of zip and tar files to another S3 bucket.
We have the code to extract the zip files working.
We need to use meta.client.upload_fileobj or meta.client.copy so if necessary multipart upload or copy will be used.

```
def unzip_file(source_bucketname, filename, target_bucketname):

    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    target_directory = source_file_name + '/'

    zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(
        bucket_name=source_bucketname, key=source_file_name)

    buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())

    with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, mode='r', allowZip64=True) as z:
        for filename in z.namelist():
            file_info = z.getinfo(filename)

            s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
                z.open(filename),
                Bucket=target_bucketname,
                Key=f'{source_file_name}/{filename}'
            )
```

We can't get the extraction of tar files to work.

```
def untar_file(source_bucketname, filename, target_bucketname):

    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    target_directory = source_file_name + '/'

    s3_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucketname, Key=filename)
    tar_file = s3_object['Body'].read()
    file_object = io.BytesIO(tar_file)

    with tarfile.open(fileobj=file_object, mode=('r:gz')) as z:
        for filename in z.getmembers():
            s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
                filename, #z.open(filename)
                Bucket=target_bucketname,
                Key=f'{source_file_name}/{filename}'
            )
```

The problem is specifying the filename object in the meta.client.upload_fileobj command.
We have tried z.open(filename)

We would be very grateful if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Anon Coward answered this but the answer seems to have been deleted.

```
s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
        filename, #z.open(filename)
        Bucket=target_bucketname,
        Key=f'{source_file_name}/{filename}'
    )
```

needs to be

```
s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
        z.extractfile(filename),
        Bucket=target_bucketname,
        Key=f'{source_file_name}/{filename.name}'
    )
```

The source file needs to be z.extractfile(filename) and the destination filename needs to be filename.name.

Many thanks Anon Coward